# Populate ListView from XML file

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-xml

I have the following sample XML file from which i need to poplutate a ListView. I've been playing for hours but I don't know the best way to go about it. I want to use Linq to achieve this but my knowledge is somewhat lacking. It is a Winforms c# project.

```
<DMs>
  <dataModule>
    <DMC>11111</DMC>
    <techName>Test Techname 1</techName>
    <infoName>info 1</infoName>
    <status>complete</status>
    <notes>Note 1</notes>
  </dataModule>
  <dataModule>
    <DMC>22222</DMC>
    <techName>Test Techname 2</techName>
    <infoName>info 2</infoName>
    <status>in work</status>
    <notes>Note 2</notes>
  </dataModule>
  <dataModule>
    <DMC>33333</DMC>
    <techName>Test Techname 3</techName>
    <infoName>info 3</infoName>
    <status>QA required</status>
    <notes>Note 3</notes>
  </dataModule>
  </DMs>
```

I have the following very basic code which successfully populates the first column of the listview with the DMC element text, but i need the sibling elements (techName, infoname, status and notes) to populate the other columns of the listview.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(CSDBpath + projectName + "\\Data.xml");
            var DMCs = from item in doc.Descendants("dataModule")
                       select item.Element("DMC").Value;

                foreach (var dmc in DMCs)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dmc);
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);

                }
```

Comment: Is it ASP.NET or WinForms?

Comment: You want to read about projections...

Comment: It's Winforms. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1108296/763026

Comment: Why can't you use XMLDataSource?

Comment: @ Angshuman - i've tried this solution but i don't have a 'DataSource' method option.

Comment: @ RVG, perhaps i can but i'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add appropriate columns to the `ListView`, and the fill the subitems for each item:

```
// Add required columns
listView1.Columns.Add("DMC");
listView1.Columns.Add("Tech Name");
listView1.Columns.Add("Info Name");
listView1.Columns.Add("Status");
listView1.Columns.Add("Notes");

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(CSDBpath + projectName + "\\Data.xml");

foreach (var dm in doc.Descendants("dataModule"))
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem( new string[]
    {
        dm.Element("DMC").Value,
        dm.Element("techName").Value,
        dm.Element("infoName").Value,
        dm.Element("status").Value,
        dm.Element("notes").Value
    });
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(CSDBpath + projectName + "\\Data.xml");
 var DMCs = from item in doc.Descendants("dataModule")
            select new {
                        dmc: item.Element("techName").Value, 
                        techName: item.Element("DMC").Value, 
                        infoName: item.Element("infoName").Value, 
                        status: item.Element("status").Value, 
                        notes: item.Element("notes").Value, 

                       };

 ListViewItem item = null;
 foreach (var dmc in DMCs)
 {
     item = new ListViewItem(dmc);
     listView1.Items.Add(item);
 }
```

I hope this will work, but didn't tested yet..